# TensorFlow GradCAM - model.fit() - ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, training-data

As part of assignment 4, Coursera CV TF course, my code fails in `model.fit()`

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=
   ['accuracy'],optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001))
# shuffle and create batches before training

model.fit(train_batches,epochs=25)
```

with error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible
```

Any hint at where problem might come from? I suspect bad format or type for `train_batches`:

```
train_data = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split='train[:80%]', as_supervised=True) 
augmented_training_data = train_data.map(augmentimages)
train_batches = augmented_training_data.batch(32)
```

Comment: I suspect it is coming from your model architecture, could you please share that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not familiar with the exact code of the architecture, I suspect it is this line:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=
   ['accuracy'],optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001))
```

You may be using `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy` for binary classification with 1 neuron at the output, but this is only an assumption considering I do not have the code and architecture to look at; in fact I am 99% that the issue is from there.